# Typescript union type arrays as array function parameters, e.g. in $q.all

Tags: angularjs, typescript

Consider a method that is declared as (simplified from AngularJS IQService):

```
all<T1, T2>(values: [IPromise<T1>, IPromise<T2>]): IPromise<[T1, T2]>;
```

It takes an array where first item is a `IPromise<T1>` and the second item a `IPromise<T2>`. When using this declaration, I was somehow suprised, that I cannot use this method like this:

```
var promises = [a(), b()];
$q.all(promises).then(/*...*/);

> TS2329 Index signature is missing in type '(IPromise<A> | IPromise<B>)[]'
```

while this works fine:

```
$q.all([a(), b()]).then(/*...*/);
```

I understand, that `var p = [a(), b()];` creates p as `(A|B)[]`. My question is, what's the best way to make `(A|B)[]` compatible to `[A, B]` in such cases. So how could I fix this without explicitly referencing the types of `a()` and `b()`, but without lossing type information in the return value of `$q.all`

```
var promises: [???] = [a(), b()];
$q.all(promises).then(/*...*/);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can tell the compiler explicitly overriding the "default" type inferring using this syntax:

```
let promises = [a(), b()] as [IPromise<number>, IPromise<boolean>];
```

or you could create a helper function, which would "wrap" it for you so that you don't have to explicitly define the type:

```
function toArray<T1, T2>(a: T1, b: T2) {
    return [a, b] as [T1, T2];
}
```

Comment: of course, but that's what I meant when I said "without explicitly referencing the types of a() and b()"

Comment: oh I see, sorry, missed that one. In that case I would suggest creating a simple helper function, I can't see any other way. Updated the answer with it.

Comment: no problem;) I filed an issue [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9216) and got exactly the same workaround:) There is an open issue for tuple literals [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9217)